# Nagios 4.4.1 slows to crawl after about 1 week with frequent 100% CPU utilization

Tags: linux, monitoring, nagios, ubuntu-16.04

We are running a new Nagios Core server on Ubuntu 16 Server. Everything was running fine until today when all of a sudden, the site slowed to a crawl. Looking at top command results, we are seeing consistent 99-100% usage by either the nagios or *.cgi processes (web UI). Nothing changed. We also see that polling latencies have increased dramatically. We ran into this once before and decided to remove the install, build a fresh compile and deploy as new. That was a few weeks ago, and now we are back to the same thing. Anyone else run into this that has a fix? Thanks.

```
top - 11:33:30 up 7 days, 22:38,  1 user,  load average: 2.00, 1.91, 1.41
Tasks: 161 total,   2 running, 154 sleeping,   0 stopped,   5 zombie
%Cpu(s): 31.1 us,  3.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 63.3 id,  2.2 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 12174388 total,  7690680 free,  1430508 used,  3053200 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  4067324 total,  4067324 free,        0 used. 10267768 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
27230 nagios    20   0  782008 767708   2752 D  87.7  6.3 189:32.12 nagios
16175 www-data  20   0  781988 136336  68412 R  48.5  1.1   0:01.46 status.cgi
16174 sysadmin  20   0   41776   3836   3248 R   0.3  0.0   0:00.01 top
31422 www-data  20   0  296772  11440   3424 S   0.3  0.1   0:00.15 apache2


top - 11:33:33 up 7 days, 22:38,  1 user,  load average: 2.00, 1.91, 1.41
Tasks: 161 total,   2 running, 154 sleeping,   0 stopped,   5 zombie
%Cpu(s): 24.9 us,  0.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 28.4 id, 45.9 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 12174388 total,  7550296 free,  1570912 used,  3053180 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  4067324 total,  4067324 free,        0 used. 10127412 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
16175 www-data  20   0  922568 413956 205436 R 100.0  3.4   0:04.48 status.cgi
27230 nagios    20   0  782008 767708   2752 D   2.0  6.3 189:32.18 nagios
  323 root      20   0       0      0      0 D   1.0  0.0   0:24.04 jbd2/dm-0-8
    1 root      20   0   37792   5980   4144 S   0.0  0.0   0:10.31 systemd
```

[image]

Comment: It is the status.cgi that is at 100%.  Can you check your web server logs?  Are you getting hit by some kind of password guessing tool or something?

Comment: @Zoredache I doubt it. This server is only accessible internally, no public access. Apache logs show only 3-4 client PCs.

Comment: what are the hardware specs of that server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving this issue in part by working with the community over on the Nagios site. Here is the solution:

1) Downloaded, compiled and installed a working build of Nagios from Githib per their recommendation. There is a bug in the version of Nagios (4.4.1) that causes hosts/services to stay in a soft state causing rechecks to happen more frequently.

Maintenance Branch: https://github.com/NagiosEnterprises/na ... tree/maint

2) Renaming the retention.dat & status.dat files was also necessary because they had reached a file size of over 8GB each. Presumably the parsing of these files was causing all the delays.

It has been working perfectly since then for a few weeks now with no degradation in performance. I hope this helps others.